# Single Consumer via Camel Quartz in clustered environment

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I want is to have a **single master consumer** in a cluster. I have used camel-quartz in my application in order to run cron jobs in a clustered fashion.

My use case is I need to run a single consumer once when my spring boot application starts in a clustered environment,

I am using **simple trigger** with *repeatCount = 0*. But clustering is not working properly as I get logs on both nodes in the cluster.

### Route

```kotlin
@Component
class QuartzRoutes(
    private val schedulerFactoryBean: SchedulerFactoryBean,
    private val camelContext: CamelContext
) : EndpointRouteBuilder() {

    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger { }


    fun getCamelQuartzEndpoint(groupName: String, triggerName: String, camelContext: CamelContext): Endpoint {
        val quartzComponent = QuartzComponent(camelContext)
        quartzComponent.scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.scheduler
        quartzComponent.isInterruptJobsOnShutdown = true
        quartzComponent.isAutoStartScheduler = false

        val endpoint =
            quartzComponent.createEndpoint("quartz://$QUARTZ_GROUP_NAME$triggerName?stateful=true&durableJob=true&trigger.repeatInterval=3000&trigger.repeatCount=0&trigger.misfireInstruction=4")


        if (!camelContext.componentNames.contains("quartz")) {
            camelContext.addComponent("quartz", quartzComponent)
        }
        return endpoint
    }

    override fun configure() {

        val triggerName = "myTimerTrigger"
        val routeId = "${triggerName}_route"

        val endpoint = getCamelQuartzEndpoint(QUARTZ_GROUP_NAME, triggerName, camelContext)

        from(endpoint)
            .routeId(routeId)
            .process { exchange ->
                logger.info { "Simple trigger fired Connecting to Endpoint 1: $exchange" }
                Thread.sleep(240000) // mimic task
            }
            .end()

    }
}
```

## Spring boot quartz configuration

```yaml
spring:
  lifecycle:
    timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 45s
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/quartztest?stringtype=unspecified&reWriteBatchedInserts=true
  quartz:
    startup-delay: 5s
    wait-for-jobs-to-complete-on-shutdown: true
    overwrite-existing-jobs: true
    job-store-type: JDBC
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: ALWAYS
    properties:
      org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO
      org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: true
      org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true
      org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties: false
      org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 5
      org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass: 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate'
```

I have created a sample application for this issue on GitHub [Link](https://github.com/Zaky7/QuartzTest)

Answer (score 0):

Camel has some built-in clustering capabilities - see [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/clustering.html).

In your particular case, you could model a route which is taking the leadership when starting the Quartz consumer, preventing thereby other node(s) from firing the cron job on the same scheduled time.

Comment: thanks, I had previously used Zookeeper for such setup but due to a configuration issue on the zookeeper, it was not starting and I had to spend a hard time fixing that. 
Therefore I want to move to something more stable like quartz. Do we have any quartz implementation of clustering service?